# How can I dump OpenGL RenderBuffer to PNG or JPG image?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I'm working on a project which uses OpenGL framebuffer/renderbuffer to draw freehand lines. This App uses OpenGL ES 1.x and I can't figure out how to dump current screen to PNG or JPG image.

Thanks for reading this question.

From OpenGL Newbie.

Codes used to create frame buffer and render buffer.

```
// Generate IDs for a framebuffer object and a color renderbuffer
glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &viewFramebuffer);
glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &viewRenderbuffer);

glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);

// This call associates the storage for the current render buffer with the EAGLDrawable (our CAEAGLLayer)
// allowing us to draw into a buffer that will later be rendered to screen wherever the layer is (which corresponds with our view).
[context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES fromDrawable:(id<EAGLDrawable>)self.layer];
glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);

glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth);
glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &backingHeight);

// For this sample, we also need a depth buffer, so we'll create and attach one via another renderbuffer.
glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &depthRenderbuffer);
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, depthRenderbuffer);
glRenderbufferStorageOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES, backingWidth, backingHeight);
glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, depthRenderbuffer);
```

Comment: I found a web page with related information. http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/23525-cgimagecreate-alpha.html

Comment: Here is another one. http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=1861

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
-(UIImage *)dumpImage
{
    GLubyte *buffer = (GLubyte *) malloc(backingWidth * backingHeight * 4);
    GLubyte *buffer2 = (GLubyte *) malloc(backingWidth * backingHeight * 4);

    GLvoid *pixel_data = nil;
    glReadPixels(0, 0, backingWidth, backingHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid *)buffer);

    /* make upside down */

    for (int y=0; y<backingHeight; y++) {
        for (int x=0; x<backingWidth*4; x++) {
            buffer2[y * 4 * backingWidth + x] = buffer[(backingHeight - y - 1) * backingWidth * 4 + x];
        }
    }

    // make data provider from buffer
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer2, backingWidth * backingHeight * 4, freeImageData);

    // set up for CGImage creation
    int bitsPerComponent = 8;
    int bitsPerPixel = 32;
    int bytesPerRow = 4 * backingWidth;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
    // Use this to retain alpha
    //CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast;
    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(backingWidth, backingHeight, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, NO, renderingIntent);

    // make UIImage from CGImage
    UIImage *newUIImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

    return newUIImage;
}
```

freeImageData() frees data later.

```
void freeImageData(void *info, const void *data, size_t size) 
{
    //printf("freeImageData called");
    free((void*)data);
}
```

Comment: To finish this thought, you can use UIImagePNGRepresentation or UIImageJPEGRepresentation to get an NSData containing a UIImage encoded as PNG or JPEG. You can then output the NSData anywhere you want on disk (or transmit it or whatever you want), or use UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum to write directly to the photos album.

Comment: If speed is your concern, you could flip the image on GPU before reading it. It can be done either by drawing the quad with flipped texture coordinates in Fixed-Function mode or by utilizing a simple shader.