# OpenGLES 2.0 texture rendering

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I'm creating a drawing app and I need the end result to be saved as a png image.  But I then need to be able to edit the image with further drawing.

Is a framebuffer object the way to go here?  Rendering into an offscreen texture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how you want to edit the image afterwards. There are two parts to your question: 
    1) Saving the image as a png
    2) Editing the image after drawing to it

1) It is straightforward to save a frame buffer drawing as a png. There is a similar question here for OpenGL ES 1.x (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062978/how-can-i-dump-opengl-renderbuffer-to-png-or-jpg-image) that should be a good base to work off of.

2) It depends how soon you want to edit the image. If you are editing the image continuously throughout the program, then keep everything in memory in the frame buffer and only write to a png when you are done editing. If you need to draw on top of the image at a later time (for instance, when you reopen the program) you can save as a png and then load the png as a texture for a new frame buffer when you want to edit the image again. When you draw to this new frame buffer, you will be drawing on top of the texture (which was your previous image).